# How can i make a toggle on and off command for this command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So im trying to make an anti-link/anti-swear discord bot but idk how to make a toggle command. This is the code that i have made so far.

```
import discord


client = discord.Client()
key = "Secret"


block_words = ["http://", "https://"]


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Bot logged in as {client.user}") 

# The on_message event happens when a message gets sent on the server
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):


    if msg.author != client.user:

        for text in block_words:

                await msg.delete()
                return 


        print("Not Deleting...")
        

client.run(key)
```

If anyone can make it please make it i'd appriciate it :)

Comment: also i don't want the moderator role thingy this is just a "demo" code.

Answer (score 0):

Make a json file or use a database to store if the server wants it enabled or disabled.

```
import discord
import json
from discord.ext import commands


client = discord.Client()
key = "Secret"


block_words = ["http://", "https://"]


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Bot logged in as {client.user}") 

# The on_message event happens when a message gets sent on the server
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
   with open('automod.json', 'r') as f:
      data = json.load(f)

    if msg.author != client.user and data[msg.guild.id]:  # Filter words only if enabled

        for text in block_words:
           if text in msg.content:  # Check if blocked words are there in the message content
                await msg.delete()
                return 


        print("Not Deleting...")

# Make a command to configure the automod
@client.command(name='put_name_here')
@commands.has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
async def auto_mod_config(ctx):
   with open('automod.json', 'r') as f:
      data = json.load(f)
      data[ctx.guild.id] = not data[ctx.guild.id]  # Toggle happens here
   
   with open('automod.json', 'w') as f:
      json.dump(data, f)

client.run(key)
```

This is how `automod.json` should look:

```
{
   guild_id(the id of the server): true or false
}
```